# How to get the caller path from Ruby/Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

In Ruby/Rake(a gem for Ruby), current file path can be get through `Dir.pwd` and `__FILE__`.

There are times I want to get the caller's path, like to figure out a relative path the caller provided which is relative to their path (but not relative to the path of the Rakefile).

**An example**

In a Rakefile from directory `/home/me/workspace/proj`:

```
# ...

task :foo do
  file_name = ENV['WHICH_FILE']

  # As I can not get the caller dir, give it the Rakefile dir instead
  caller_dir = Dir.pwd

  file_name = "#{call_dir}/#{file_name}" unless file_name&.match? /^\//
  puts File.read file_name
  # ...
end

# ...
```

If a caller provides the absolute path of the target file, no problem:

```
$ WHICH_FILE=/home/me/workspace/proj/suba/subb/subc/file.txt rake foo
```

If a caller in `/home/me/workspace/proj` provides a relative path, still no problem:

```
$ WHICH_FILE=suba/subb/subc/file.txt rake foo
```

If a caller in `/home/me/workspace/proj/suba` provides a relative path, the file_name may point to a wrong place:

```
$ WHICH_FILE=subb/subc/file.txt rake foo
```

Now `file_name` would be `/home/me/workspace/proj/subb/subc/file.txt`, which may not be what the caller want.

**Questions**

Is it possible to get the caller's path in Ruby/Rake? If it's possible, how?

Comment: Can't you just call `caller`?

Comment: @sawa seems like this `Kernel#caller` the not the outter caller (or bash caller)

Comment: @hxpax what do you mean by that? can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: @maxpleaner updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell where the user is right now, like you said, with `Dir.pwd`, but there's no way to guess which absolute path the user really wants.

This is why most scripts (or apps, etc) either have a `ROOT_DIR` that allows you to default to that as a prefix for the rest of the directory structure or just assume the file passed is under the current folder (shown by pwd).

Your choice is either set this ROOT_DIR somewhere in your code or just being open to the chance the user gives you a relative path to a file without really knowing what the absolute route to that file is and just assume is under their current dir.

Comment: Thanks. So it's not possible to get the outter caller's path. We can only get the script path. Did I miss somthing?

Comment: You can know 2 things:

1) The current path (`Dir.pwd`)
2) Where your program is (`__FILE__`)

But this is not even the bigger issue, because you're depending on a variable set by the user at execution time, so there's no exact way to guess which is the correct route rather than having the user telling you so.

Comment: It turns out, just Rake has such a problem, the Dir.pwd will only give you what you really want in Rakefiles.

Comment: What do you mean?
`Dir.pwd` is Ruby and it's not monkeypatched by rake afaik: 
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Dir.html#method-c-pwd

Comment: most of the time , the Rakefile is not called directly by the user, but the rake executalbe from another place when the user typed `rake`

Comment: You can only call rake within a folder that contains a `Rakefile`, I still don't know what you mean, but meh... if you figured it out it's fine I guess.

Comment: Yeah, but this does not make the problem gone, still it will apera when you are in a sub folder

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Rake finds the Rakefile (up in the parent directories if needed) and executes tasks *from the directory of the Rakefile*[1]. For example, if you have some simple rule task how to compile `.c` source files to `.o`, and you `cd` to the source directory in your project:

```
proj/
  rakefile
  src/ <-- you are here
    foo.c
```

Then you cannot run the rule on the `foo.c` file in the *current working directory* by just calling

```
$ rake foo.o   # won't work
```

Rake will complain that it does not know how to make `foo.o` task. Because it executes the rules from the `proj` directory and does not find the corresponding `proj/foo.c` file there.

No matter where you are, you have to give it the relative file from the *top directory* (= the one with the rakefile):

```
$ pwd
.../proj/
$ ls
src/
$ cd src/
$ ls
foo.c
$ rake src/foo.c
```

As far as I understand, the `rake` executable first finds the rakefile, then `cd` to that directory, and calls the Ruby code from there. So, as far as Ruby code is concerned, everything is executed from the rakefile directory. All the `__FILE__`, `Dir.pwd` etc Ruby stuff is set to the rakefile directory.

But notice that you can combine your suggestion about the env variable from the user (aka the caller) with just changing the current path inside Ruby. Something like this at the beginning of the rakefile:

```
# rakefile
if ENV['CWD']
  Dir.chdir(ENV['CWD'])                                                                                                                     
end

puts "project_dir #{Dir.pwd}" # confirm where it is

... rules, tasks etc
```

Then in Bash:

```
$ pwd
.../proj/
$ cd src/
$ CWD=`pwd` rake foo.c

# or with an alias
$ alias rk='CWD=`pwd` rake'
$ rk foo.c

# or in fish
$ alias rk "CWD=(pwd) rake"
```

So, rake will `cd` to the current directory where the user called it, before executing all the Ruby code to figure out the rake tasks etc. It can be a handy trick. But of course it may mess things up, if there are dependencies with other subdirectories under the rakefile top directory.

Also, it could be nice to expand this trick: check if the requested task matches one of tasks/rules for *files*, or if the task name matches a relative-path regexp like `./file` etc, and only then do the `Dir.chdir(ENV['CWD'])` etc.

Rake is made more for Ruby-Rails sort of tasks, that are done on the whole project of some web app, not some separate files within subdirectories. In that setting, it makes sense to run everything from the top directory. But "it's Ruby code"[1] -- you can modify it how you like. Here the challenging part is how to distinguish the cases when the requested task name is a relative file path from the user's CWD, or a regular task, or a path from the rakefile directory, etc. Also, there may be complications with the dependencies between project subdirectories.

[1] [Basic Rake by Jim Weirich on Confreaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFPWDzHWjEY)

[2] As an ad: [Enhanced Shell Scripting with Ruby by devdangeon](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/enhanced-shell-scripting-ruby#toc-2)